# Can CSS Grids be used in JSX Inline styles on Electron?

Tags: css, reactjs, electron

So I am creating an Electron app that allows the user to create an invoice and then produce a PDF of that invoice. I'm using a PDF npm package that allows me to pass in HTML. So I am using JSX to create the invoice dynamically then I am turning that JSX into an HTML string. Because I am doing it like this I cannot use typical css files to set styling. So I need to use JSX's inline styling. But for some reason I can't get it to work with CSS Grids. Am I doing anything wrong. I've tried researching it and can't really find any good information on what I'm trying to do.

```
let headerStyle = {
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: '3fr 1fr',
        gridTemplateRows: 'auto auto',
    }

    let invoiceHeaderInfoStyle = {
        gridColumn: '2 / 3',
        gridRow: '1 / 2'
    }

    let invoiceHeaderCompanyInfoStyle = {
        gridColumn: '1 / 2',
        gridRow: '1 / 2'
    }

    let invoiceHeaderClientInfoStyle = {
        gridColumnStart: '1',
        gridColumnEnd: '2',
        gridRow: '2 / 3'
    }

    return (<div>
        <header style={headerStyle}>
            <h1>Invoice</h1>
            <section style={invoiceHeaderInfoStyle}>
                <div className="invoiceHeaderInfoDetails">
                    <span>Invoice #:</span>
                    <span>{invoice.number}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="invoiceHeaderInfoDetails">
                    <span>Date:</span>
                    <span>{invoice.date}</span>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section style={invoiceHeaderCompanyInfoStyle}>
                <div><p>Company Name</p></div>
                <div><p>Some City, KS</p></div>
                <div><p>(555)555-5555</p></div>
                <div><p>companyname@email.com</p></div>
            </section>
            <section style={invoiceHeaderClientInfoStyle}>
                <div>{this.getFormattedAddressHeader()}</div>
            </section>
        </header>
    </div>)
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe this will help https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4565

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I'm looking for, because grids work in my electron app everywhere else like normal. Just doesn't work when I create the pdf. I can style it with other css properties but it would be lovely to get grids to work of course :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you figured this out, but for others, you have to include `style` as JSX object:

```
import style from './app.css';

export default () => (
...

<div className={style.box}>A</div>

...
```

It's interesting the element style works in normal way, but references to classes have to be specified as JSX variables.